# Compiling mathgl C-Example

Tags: c, gcc, mathgl

I'm trying to compile the first example of the MathGL library in C:

http://mathgl.sourceforge.net/doc_en/Examples.html

```
#include <mgl2/mgl_cf.h>

int main()
{
  HMGL gr = mgl_create_graph(600,400);
  mgl_fplot(gr,"sin(pi*x)","","");
  mgl_write_frame(gr,"test.png","");
  mgl_delete_graph(gr);
}
```

I installed libmgl-dev using aptitude and rejected the first option offered, because aptitude wanted to remove a number of different programs and accepted the second option, which only upgraded a few.

If I try to compile:

```
gcc test.c  -o test -lmgl
In file included from /usr/include/mgl2/mgl_cf.h:29:0,
                 from test.c:1:
/usr/include/mgl2/data_cf.h:318:78: error: unknown type name ‘bool’
 EXPORT mgl_fft(double *x, long s, long n, const void *wt, void *ws, bool inv);
```

So I tried to add `#include <stdbool.h>` and tried flags like `-std=gnu11` or `-std=c11` and `-std=c99`. None of which worked. I tried adding the flag `-lmgl` (I even read that I should put it at the very end).

How do I compile this example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have an old version of the library, in which this is a bug.

See this [bug report](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mathgl/wSoS9I3C7JA/X3TSrdysyD0J)
from May 2013. The Alexey Balakin who confirms the bug is the lead developer of MathGL.

See that the bug is fixed in MathGL 2.3.3 version of [data_ch.h](https://fossies.org/dox/mathgl-2.3.3/data__cf_8h_source.html),
where the declaration is:

```
void MGL_EXPORT mgl_fft(double *x, long s, long n, const void *wt, void *ws, int inv);
```

with `bool` replaced by `int`.

Comment: ok I recompilled from source and it worked fine. I'll report it to mint as a bug.